# How to keep a user logged on? Is it possible with ExpressJS and Passport?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a server in node.js using express and passport with the `passport-local` strategy.

I have the users in the database and through passport I'm able to authenticate them, unfortunately when a second request comes from the same client the `req.isAuthenticated()` method returns `false`.
There is also no user in the request (`req.user = undefined`).

I've also checked and  when doing the authentication although I get back a user from `passport.authenticate('local'...` I do not get `req.user` populated then. If I try to set it up manually it just doesn't propagate for following requests.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, here is my code.

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
compass = require('node-compass'),
routes = require('./server/routes')
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
Database = require('./server/repositories/database'),
Configuration = require('./server/config').Config,
crypto = require('crypto');

var app = express();

app.enable("jsonp callback");

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(email, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      var userService = new UserService();
      userService.login(email, crypto.createHash('md5').update(password).digest("hex"), function(error, user) {
        if (error) done(error, user);
        else if (!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'wrong credentials'}); 
        return done(null, user);
      });
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  var userService = new UserService();
  userService.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', Configuration.Port);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser()); 
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(compass({
    project: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
      sass: 'styles'
  }));
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
  });
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));
});

routes.configure(app);

Database.open(function() { 
  app.listen(Configuration.Port, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + Configuration.Port);
  });
});
```

routes.js

```
var Configuration = require('./config').Config;
var ApiResult = require('../model/apiResult').ApiResult;
var ApiErrorResult = require('../model/apiErrorResult').ApiErrorResult;
var ApiReturnCodes = require('../model/apiReturnCodes').ApiReturnCodes;
var passport = require('passport');

var usersController = require('./controllers/usersController');

exports.configure = function(app) {
  function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    else {res.send(new ApiErrorResult(ApiReturnCodes.NOT_LOGGED_IN, null));}
  }

  app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err || !user) { console.log(info); res.send(new ApiErrorResult(ApiReturnCodes.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND, null)); }
      // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
      // `req.user` contains the authenticated user
      else res.send(new ApiResult(user));
    })(req,res,next);
  });

  app.get('/anotherLink', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({Code:0});
  });
}
```

When I hit the link `/anotherLink` after being authenticated I get `res.isAuthenticated()` as false.

Also when I see the `req.session` after the `ensureAuthenticated` is called I get:

```
{ cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  passport: {} }
```

What am I missing for it to save the information that that user is authenticated?
On the client side I'm using Angular only doing a simple get with the url without parameters.

If I forgot to put something here just tell me, I'll update it. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I found out what was wrong with my code.

My `passport.deserializeUser` method used the method `userService.findById`

And that called the repository... like this:

```
userRepository.findUnique({"_id": id}, callback);
```

because the `id` was generated by `MongoDB` the correct call needs to be:

```
userRepository.findUnique({"_id": new ObjectID(id)}, callback);
```

I hope this saves some time to the next person with the same problem.

With this detail, this code should work nicely for everyone wanting to use the `LocalStrategy` on the `Passport` framework.